# Data Factory - web activity returning compressed (gzip) string. Ouput unusable

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

We have been using the web activity in data factory to trigger an extract to csv form a source system from an API call. This has been running successfully for almost a year.

Now it seems that the provider has changed the response of that call to be compressed and we can do nothing about that...

Powershell and Postman can read the output just fine (a json object with a single property named "extractId") but all we get is a string representation of that compressed string/response. like this
[image]

the correct response should look like this.
[image]

the activity that runs after this one needs to read the "extractId".

I am lost as to how to make this work again in ADF.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am getting the same issue, and I suspect I am calling the same REST API as you (a time tracking system). If I figure out how to handle this, I'll post an answer here.

Comment: Probably. Replicon?  We have opened a ticket with them but it will most likely take over a month to correct on their part. We have instead setup a Azure function to run PowerShell code to initiate the extraction and return the file path to be used by copy data activity. Works great

Comment: Yeah, I did the same - except I did the workaround in PowerShell and put it in an Azure Automation runbook. I've got an open ticket with Replicon, as well as one with Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Web Activity, use [Copy Activity with HTTP as source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties). Then you can choose JSON as the data source's format, which contains the [configurable property of compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json). Select gzip, and you are done.